# Sending URL with parameters and using javascript values in parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For online payment I have to send parameters to an URL. Calculations in my site written in Javascript, Online payment company requires PHP parameters like MD5 hashing.

I tried creating hidden form and put required javascript values into input fields. And succeded.

My hidden form:

```
<form action="https://test.millikart.az:7444/gateway/payment/register" method="get" id="hiddenForm">
<input name="mid" value="unicopy" type="hidden">
<input name="amount" id="amount" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="currency" value="944" type="hidden">
<input name="description" value="" id="description" type="hidden">
<input name="reference" value="UNICSH3195319" type="hidden">
<input name="language" value="az" type="hidden">    
<input name="signature" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($signature); ?>" type="hidden">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="clearList()" >Reset</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary" id="odenis" >Pay</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("amount").value= parseInt(yekunMeblegArray.reduce(myFunc));
document.getElementById("description").value= description;

//AJAX
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "index.php",
data: $("#hiddenForm").serialize(), 

success: function(response) { 
alert("succeed")},
});
</script>
```

But before sending the URL I have to prepare $signature with PHP that should include value from javascript

My PHP:

```
<?php 

  $mid="unicopy";
  $amount=$_POST['amount'];
  $currency="944";
  $description=$_POST['desc'];
  $reference="UNICSH3195319";
  $language="az";
  $key="123456qwerty";

  $signature=strtoupper(md5(strlen($mid).$mid.strlen($amount).$amount.strlen($currency).$currency.(!empty($description)? strlen($description).$description :"0").strlen($reference).$reference.strlen($language).$language.$key));

  ?>
```

As you can see $signature includes $amount and $description variables that should get its values from javascript. I tried sending form data with AJAX but couldn't succeed. How can I achieve this? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the ajax?

Comment: @mplungjan edited my question and added AJAX

Comment: I also tried sending only two values (amount and description) with AJAX but still couldn't succeed

Comment: You are not doing anything with the ajax response and you do nt have an error function to see if it failed

Comment: Have you checked response from the call? If you are getting response without errors, try to var_dump($_POST) to see if the values were passed to the server side.

Comment: `success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },` Tried like this but still couldn't manage

Comment: @RenéBeneš I am using `$amount = $_POST['amount']` in PHP, but its value is null

Comment: @NahidMirzayev Then check if the form data was passed correctly in the request. I think that would be a problem.

Comment: @RenéBeneš when I var_dump($_POST) I get array(0) { } response

Comment: So debug the request in the Network tab of your Developer console to see what data is it actually sending and to see the content and data type of your request. Because it seems that the data is eiher 1) type that $_POST variable doesn't accept or 2) not sent correctly. I would suggest to do some debugging on the client side, for example log your $("#hiddenForm").serialize to see how it looks like.

Comment: @RenéBeneš I replaced `$("#hiddenForm").serialize` to  `"amount=" + amount` to see if problem is in this line, still get array(0)

Comment: Guys, when I use ` $('#result').html(data);` in success case I got my whole index.php. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that either:

1) `document.getElementById("amount").value= parseInt(yekunMeblegArray.reduce(myFunc));` does not set a proper value (you can debug with `console.log` statement underneath value being set.

Or

2) `$("#hiddenForm").serialize()` this function call does not generate data in the way you think it does. You should `console.log` to investigate.

I recommend you look at `contentType` and `dataType` properties of the `ajax` object in:

https://inweb.notesalong.com/id/5d78e9b04818060013b15b19/https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#notesalong:5d78e97645e451000020ae70;

Comment: The first point works because I see correct amount value in the URL when sending, and I changed `$("#hiddenForm").serialize` to `"amount=" + amount` to see if problem is in this line, still get array(0) when var_dump($_POST)